# Delete Duplicates Through Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We've got an "audit log" table that stores each item's price every day. Here's some sample data:

```
1 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/1/2012
2 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/2/2012
3 - Item 587 - $18.99 - 12/3/2012
4 - Item 587 - $18.99 - 12/4/2012
5 - Item 587 - $20.99 - 12/5/2012
6 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/6/2012
7 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/7/2012
8 - Item 587 - $17.99 - 12/8/2012
9 - Item 587 - $17.99 - 12/9/2012
10 - Item 587 - $17.99 - 12/10/2012
```

This works fine, however, this table is growing too quickly. We now need a T-SQL script to remove duplicate rows. The dataset after the script should be like this:

```
1 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/1/2012
3 - Item 587 - $18.99 - 12/3/2012
5 - Item 587 - $20.99 - 12/5/2012
6 - Item 587 - $19.99 - 12/6/2012
8 - Item 587 - $17.99 - 12/8/2012
```

It seems like a `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` is called for, but I'm unsure of how to start.

Comment: Do you have an additional unique ID?

Comment: why not make the loging function so smart that it does not make repeting values and just checks if it allready exitsts and then just not inserts it? Then you can state that the price stays the same unless it is changed. That is how I handle that

Comment: @Jester that's definitely where we want to go. In the mean time, I've got to cleanup this data.

Comment: @juergend, yes, there is a unique ID called `RECID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH DuplicateTableWithDupNumbers
as
(
    SELECT recid, itemid, price, date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY  dateDESC ) AS DupNumber
    FROM YourTable
)
delete from YourTable
where EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    from DuplicateTableWithDupNumbers as dup 
    WHERE DupNumber > 1 AND dup.recid = yourtable.recid
)
```

You can change your partition preferences as necessary. This will delete directly from your table in one query.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have these values in a table, you need something like:

```
select id, t.item, t.price, date 
from table t inner join
(select item, price, min(date) as min_date
from table
group by item, price) g on 
t.item = g.item and
t.price = g.price
t.date = g.min_date
```

Comment: That wouldn't consider the 4th row, which is again $19,99.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive СTE for check of identical values

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT Id, ItemId, Price, [date], 
         0 AS ChPrice
  FROM dbo.audit_log
  WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.Id, a.ItemId, a.Price, a.[date],
         CASE WHEN a.Price = c.Price THEN a.Id ELSE 0 END
  FROM dbo.audit_log a JOIN cte c ON a.Id = c.Id + 1  
  )
DELETE a
FROM dbo.audit_log a JOIN cte c ON a.Id = c.ChPrice
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6773/2/1)